# Pop-up transparent background css issue

Tags: css

I set a transparent background for popup. It works fine in pc. But when the keypad of smartphone is active, the background starts from somewhat middle of the screen instead oo from the top. Can anybody help me in this ?

**CSS**

```
.popup-cover {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can't say what could be the problem until you provide us related code..

Answer (score 0):

on document load find the screen height in px with JavaScript or jQuery and assign it to .popup-cover